# TFS copy changeset to branch

Tags: tfs, branch

How can I copy a changeset from the Mainline to a Branch in TFS? I can't seem to find anything on this.

Comment: Needed to right-click on the Minline folder in Source Cntrol Explorer and go to Branching and Merging ->

Answer (score 6):

You mean how to merge the change from Main line to the branch? you just right click on the main line select Branching and Merging -> Merge and choose from the drop down the branch name that you want to merge to.